# Formatting time on excel graph: from days to years

Tags: excel, time, graph, format

I'm plotting the flow of something over days. Column A is days and column A, B is the flow.

I want it to say year 1, 2, 3, 4 on the x-axis instead of the days. However, I don't think I can devide by 365 in the formatting. Help is appreacited.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you insert a Year column for column A. For Example

A       B  C
Year1   1  1%
Year1   2  1%
Year1   3  1%
Year1   4  1%
Year2   5  1%
Year2   6  1%
Year3   7  1%
Year4   8  1%
Year1N  n  1%

Then use the new column A values for your date axis.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but it was a bit more complicated than that:  I created a 'year' column by using the integer (`int`) function to identify when `days`/365 turned into years.

Thank you!